Running regression fit repeatedly in SAS
I have below data for model variable and information on the variables to be considered for regression fit
data Model_Values;
    infile datalines delimiter="," missover;
    input Y A B C;
    datalines;
20,   10, 4.5, 22.4
21,    1, 3.5, 22.1
25,   -4, 6.5, 22.9
21.5,  5, 3.5, 22.3
29,    4, 22.5, 22.22
34,    7, 3.5, 22.15
;
run;

data Result;
    infile datalines delimiter="," missover;
    input Var1 $ Var2 $ Var3 $ Intercept Coef1 Coef2 Coef3;
    datalines;
A, , , , , ,
A, B, , ,  , ,
A, B, C, ,  , ,
;
run;

Basically, based on the data Model_Values, I want to fit regression line for the variable Y on explanatory variables as provided in each row of Result and append the dataset Result with estimates of coefficients.
Could you please provide some pointer how should I achieve that.
Apologies if this question is very simple, but I am still learning SAS.
Thanks for your time.

More models that you asked for.  You can subset but think this may be exactly what you want.
    data Model_Values;
    infile datalines delimiter="," missover;
    input Y A B C;
    datalines;
20,   10, 4.5, 22.4
21,    1, 3.5, 22.1
25,   -4, 6.5, 22.9
21.5,  5, 3.5, 22.3
29,    4, 22.5, 22.22
34,    7, 3.5, 22.15
;
run;
proc rsquare outest=est;
   model y = a b c;
   run;
proc print; 
   run;



Thanks. That is indeed close. However this approach will run for all combinations i.e. if I have 5 variables then number of runs will be huge. And unnecessary, let say if I want combinations with maximum 3 variables out of 5. So my plan is, supply required combinations of variables is a separate dataset and then run regression on each row of that dataset.

You should look a documentation for PROC REG and the MODEL selection options.
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/statug/statug_reg_details08.htm

Thanks for the link. However my selection approach is custom and mostly experimental
